# Changing the default window close behaviour of JasperReports viewer to hide or dispose instead of exit 

Tags: netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using `NetBeans` and `JasperReports` to generate report. The report gets generated but when I close the Report viewer window it exits my program /application. I want the Report window to be either disposed or hidden.

Is there any way using which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution !
Did a bit of searching and found the answer to my problem here ->[JasperReports Discussion/Help Topic :  viewReport - Exits my app?](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=15397)  
I didn't add the false parameter to the function
`JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);`
:)